# glimmer.js IE Support

Tags: javascript, ember.js, glimmer.js

a new untouched glimmerjs app with ember new my-app -b @glimmer/blueprint ran in firefox and chrome but not in ie or edge.

Edge gave me following error:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number: 
app.js (3386,11)
```

IE11:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntaxfehler
app.js (7,1)
```

After adding IE11 in `config/targets.js` the app runs with "Microsoft Edge", but still not with IE11.

IE11 provides following error, which referes to a let Symbol:

```
SCRIPT5009: "Symbol" ist undefiniert
app.js (9804,1)
```

**Any other settings we need to change?**

Also it's a little bit strange that with setting IE11 the Edge problem got fixed.

Or that the default setting 'last 2 Edge versions' does not transpile to a edge compatible version...

Answer (score 1):

We got a little bit further with IE 11 and Edge support in https://github.com/glimmerjs/glimmer.js/issues/8

But still were not able to completely solve it in order to support IE 9 and 10 also.

Comment: Glimmer.js' unofficial browser support matrix is IE11, Edge (there are some bugs here, as you linked), and evergreen browsers. To support IE9 and IE10 you have to give up a lot of features for a very thin slice of the global marketshare :/

Comment: Mh that's Bad news. Then I guess I'll need to port the widget to a different technology :-( too bad, as I I love ember and so glimmerjs seemed to be a good choice for littler projects. But unfortunatelly a lot of our customers still use oder IE browsers